# Prove that an equation has a unique (convergent?) solution

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm stuck on this problem. Any advice is appreciated:

i. Prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ the equation $x^n +x - 1 = 0$ has a unique solution $r_n$.

ii. Find the limit of the sequence $(r_n)_{n\geq1}$.

Here's what I have so far (not much, sadly)

I rewrote the equation in i. to get 1 to the other side. I also believe that the solution should be positive for the few numbers that I have tried. I'm thinking about using Newton's Method but I'm not sure how effective it would be. Any advice?

Comment: (i) isn't even true. For $n = 2$, and it appears for all even $n$, there are two distinct solutions.

Comment: And indeed, when $n$ is even there  are always two solutions.

Comment: Wait, I'm sorry. I missed something. It should say "unique positive." my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for (1): increasing function.

Hint for (2): Is $r_n > 1$ or $< 1$?  For fixed $x$ in the appropriate interval, what happens to $x^n + x - 1$ as $n \to \infty$  what does that tell you about how $r_n$ relates to $x$?

Comment: For (1), would using Newton's Method work? I was considering this because of the fact that it's increasing and that the second derivative is positive (except for n=1, I think).

Comment: No, you don't  need to **find** the solution, you need to know that it exists and is unique.  This is much more basic.

Comment: Would Intermediate Value Theorem work to show that a positive solution exists and then a proof by contradiction to show that it's unique work?

Comment: Yes, that's a good plan.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the second part. I know that the sequence is bounded between 0 and 1. I also know that it's increasing, but I'm not sure how to prove it. I also think that the limit is 1, but I'm not sure how to prove this part either.

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to show that the sequence is increasing. How should I show that the limit is 1?

Comment: If $0 < p < 1$, as $n \to \infty$ we have $p^n \to 0$, so $p^n + p - 1 < 0$ for large $n$. Since $f(x) = x^n + x - 1$ is increasing as a function of $x$, that means $r_n > p$.

Comment: Thank you so much Robert!! I finished it! I really appreciate the help.